# How to rediect in htaccess .php file with many IDs

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have many old URLs that I deleted:

```
viewnews.php?id=1357570020
viewnews.php?id=1565656889
viewnews.php?id=7877878768
viewnews.php?id=7876876876
```

I have like a thousand URLs like that.  I want all those URLs redirected to my main page.  They do not exist anymore.

I want when someone goes to mysite.com/viewnews.php?id=(ANY ID HERE) to automatically forward to www.mysite.com

How do I do that in htaccess?  I have tried many things.

```
Redirect 301 /viewnews.php(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using mod_rewrite you can use following code to handle this task:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+viewnews\.php\?id=[^\s]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi,  Almost working, but it redirects to http://www.wrestleview.com/?id=1358099367 instead of wrestleview.com only.

Answer (score 0):

Use RedirectMatch instead. Reference this site: http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-query-string-redirects/

> If you need to mass-redirect a group of pages you would probably need to use the **RedirectMatch** directive.

Therefore, you use that directive and you need to tell the regex where to start "^" and where to end the regex "$". Try this:

```
RedirectMatch ^/viewnews.php?id=([0-9]*)$ http://www.mysite.com/
```

Take two pills, and call me in the morning. :D

Comment: I tried the exact code you gave me and it still doesn't work.

Comment: This is the url I'm trying, that should redirect to the main page. http://www.wrestleview.com/viewnews.php?id=1358099903