# Redirect all html extensions with the following characters in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, character

I have thousands of pages being crawled like this: (With the characters after the shtml extension)

```
news2005/1124024714.shtml&lt;/a&gt;      
news2005/1126747676.shtml&lt;/a&gt;      
news2005/1686586565.shtml&lt;/a&gt;      
news2005/1168658656.shtml&lt;/a&gt;          
news2005/1486856686.shtml&lt;/a&gt;
```

I need to put a simple redirect in htaccess that will redirect ALL

```
.shtml&lt;/a&gt; to mysite.com
```

The urls have characters, and I don't know what to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule \.shtml.+$ http://%{HTTP_HOST} [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: I tried it and it did not work. All my files with:
.shtml&lt;/a&gt; do not work.

Comment: Made a slight modification, try it now. If that doesn't work do post more details like what URI you tried and what error you got?

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work.
Here is the URL: http://www.wrestleview.com/news2005/1486856686.shtml&lt;/a&gt;

Comment: I had already tested above code and it worked fine. You can try yourself here: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ most likely you have some other conflicting rules or else some local config issue stopping above rule to work.

Comment: Maybe we misunderstood each other. It says Output URL is: http://localhost/wrestleview.com/news2005/1486856686.shtml 
That's incorrect.  Plus the localhost shouldnot be there. I need the redirect url to be just wrestleview.com (main page).  All .shtml files with the &lt;/gt: to be redirected to the main site.  And all .shtml files with no weird characters to stay the same.

Comment: Why does the output say localhost? and the full URL? I just need the site URL so it can forward to that.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Alright I edited my answer. Now `http://www.wrestleview.com/news2005/1486856686.shtml&lt;/a&gt` will be redirected to `http://www.wrestleview.com/`. In my previous answer this URI was being redirected to `http://www.wrestleview.com/news2005/1486856686.shtml`

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your help, but it still doesn't work.  Here is a screenshot of my htaccess. http://i48.tinypic.com/1f8lky.png

Comment: Now I can see that `http://www.wrestleview.com/news2005/1486856686.shtml&lt;/a&gt` is being redirected to `http://www.wrestleview.com/` with 301. Is that not what you wanted?

Comment: So sorry about that. Wow, it worked!  For 15 minutes after I applied your answer, I couldn't get it to work.  Must have been a caching issue.  Thank you very much! Really!

I have one final problem, it's been a week, not resolved, when you have time, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826411/how-to-rediect-in-htaccess-php-file-with-many-ids.  It seems so simple.

Comment: Ok I will look into that other problem of yours. Can you pls mark this answer as accepted meanwhile.